# Waiting for build to finish in android studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been working on a project since a long time in android studio and it does not show any problems but since i have updated my windows the app preview is constantly showing "waiting for build to finsh".
I dont understand why, i have tried some approaches i have searched in google and stackoverflow but nothing helped me so far!
I tried 
-sync project with gradle files
-invalidate cache and restart
-rebuilding several times

Any reply will be appreciated.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow this steps:

**First solution**

1. Close your project
2. Enter on your project folder in Explorer
3. Delete `.gradle` folder
4. Delete `.idea` folder
5. Launch Android Studio and open your project again
6. Rebuild project.

**Second Solution**

Enter on `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML` on the right corner appear `Set from... > Predefined Style > Android`

Then restart your `Android Studio` and should works

**Third Solution**

Enter on `File > Settings > Experimental`. On `Editor` section, put `Fastest` option in `Layout Editor quality setting`

Restart your `Android Studio`.